# implementation of algebraic multigrid solver in c++

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical, solver

I am looking for an algebraic multigrid solver in c++, So far I have just found LASPACK which is nice, but requires a lot of coding just to setup the multigrid levels etc, and the documentation isn't great. Are there any good alternatives?

Comment: Did you have a look at the dune package (http://www.dune-project.org/) They probably have some AMG stuff in there.

Comment: You'll probably get more answers at scicomp.stackexchange.com